# Debugging output from within Javascript embedded in Python

Tags: javascript, python, gtk, webkit

I am running Python3 with GTK and WebKit2.WebView:

```
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('WebKit2', '4.0')
```

I have javascript code in a Python variable and run it with:

```
my_webview.run_javascript(my_javascript_code)
```

**How can I output debugging information from within javascript code?**

I tried `console.log()` and `alert()`, but nothing showed up, also, `debugger;` does not work

I preferably do not want to install other things, like NodeJS, ...